# 3D trigonometry problem

Tags: trigonometry

[image]

[image: HorizDiagram]

Bearing of z from X is 038 degrees

XY = 70m ,  XZ = 85m .

Q is vertically above X while P is vertically above Y such that PQ = 74m and 
Angle of elevation of Q from Y is 20 degrees

QX = (tan(20) x 70 )m

I need to Find the height of PY

My workings till I got stuck ,

QYX = 20 degree

PYQ = XQY = 90-20 = 70 degrees

Can I get a hint on how to continue ? Thanks a lot

Comment: How can $QZ=70\tan20$ (= approx 25m) when the distance XZ is 85m?

Comment: He means QX. Also, further down, XQY must be 90 minus XQY. But what is the actual question?

Comment: @almagest  Yes , sorry it was a typo .

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why Z is relevant. The horizontal distance of Q from P is 70 and the total distance 74, so the vertical distance is $\sqrt{74^2-70^2}=24$. The height of Q is $70\tan 20=25.478$, so the height of P is 1.5478m.